# How to debug a "rpc error with payload"

Tags: metamask, json-rpc, contract-debugging, ganache-cli, ethjs

Debugging smart contract errors can be surprisingly hard. There is one particular kind of error that annoys me the most: the infamous **rpc error with payload**.

For instance, just a few hours ago, while deploying a smart contract from the front-end using `new web3.eth.Contract().deploy()` into `ganache-cli`, I got the following in the browser's console:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {
  "id": 4972589614702,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "params": ["<a long hex string>"],
  "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction"
} [object Object]
```

I've seen other errors like this while googling it, except the last part, `[object Object]`, contains an actual error message. But in my case, no.

I tried converting the long hex string to Unicode, but no luck:

```
> web3.utils.toUtf8('<a long hex string>')
Uncaught Error: Invalid UTF-8 detected
```

Then I tried with the `.toAscii` method and got garbled text. Some of it was legible, though; here's a sample:

```
'\u0003\u0019\u0016R` \u0001P[PPPP`@Q\u0003
a\u0017)Wþ[\u0004PPPPPVþSafeMath: multiplication overflow¢ebzzr1X \u001aó9r\n' +
  '¢¥Ä
```

However, since there were other error strings as well, I doubt that this is the actual error. So maybe it was fruitless to try to decode that hex string.

After banging my head against the wall for some time, I `truffle compile`d the solidity code again, copied the new JSON into my front-end, and things were working again. Most people seem to solve these errors in seemingly random ways like this, but there should be a less frustrating path. So I have two questions for you:

1. What steps do you recommend to debug this kind of error?
2. Is there an issue raised somewhere to make handling this kind of error a little bit more dev-friendly?

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes appears when Metamask's nonce cache becomes invalid after ganache has been restarted.

In that case the solution is to reset Metamask, Settings - Advanced - Reset Account.

Comment: Never sleep on resetting on Metamask. I've wrestled with "bugs" for hours just to have it be this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial list of things to try after getting that error when deploying a contract:

- Increase the gas
- Make sure the constructor arguments are OK
- Reset Metamask
- Recompile the smart contract
- Remove any require statements from the constructor